# Nginx codeigniter setup

Tags: nginx, codeigniter

I'm trying to set up Nginx to serve CodeIgniter as per the official docs: https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/recipes/codeigniter. The problem is, I have no clue what the directive `fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000` is supposed to do. I mean, there's nothing running on port 9000 on my machine (or is there? How can I be sure?). How do I set this up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000` is a directive that lets NGINX know that it has to pass the requests to the PHP Fast CGI processor. For this directive to work you will have to install the PHP-FPM module and configure it.

Comment: Thank you. Can you point me to a tutorial or something that shows how to configure PHP-FPM for this case?

Comment: What is your Operating System?

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: https://www.howtoforge.com/installing-nginx-with-php5-fpm-and-mysql-on-ubuntu-14.04-lts-lemp